# Why am I getting 404 when the route matches? ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been stuck on this issue for several hours now.

I have a controller called 'DecisionPoint' and I have a breakpoint set on it's 'ApplicationState' action. No matter what I try I keep getting a 404 in the browser. I suspected that my route was not correct so I downloaded a route debugger and it turns our the URLs I am trying match the Controller and the action. So why do I get a 404 and never see the breakpoint hit?

/DecisionPoint/ApplicationState/no/worky --> 404

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ApplicationState(string fileName, string stateString)
        {
            string filePath = GetDpFilePath(fileName);
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.Load(filePath);
            HtmlNode stateScriptNode =
                htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/script[@id ='applicationState']");
            stateScriptNode.InnerHtml = "var applicationStateJSON =" + stateString;
            htmlDocument.Save(filePath);

            return Json("State Updated");
```

Route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "DecisionPointState", // Route name
        "DecisionPoint/ApplicationState/{fileName}/{stateString}", // URL with parameters
        new {controller = "DecisionPoint", action = "ApplicationState"} // Parameter defaults
    );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );


        }`
**Update**
```

I create a whole new controller and it works. This is now what my route table looks like. The state controller correclty routes to SaveState

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           "StateRoute", // Route name
           "State/SaveState/{file}/{state}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "State", action = "SaveState", file = UrlParameter.Optional, state = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "DPStateRoute", // Route name
           "DecisionPoint/ApplicationState/{file}/{state}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "DecisionPoint", action = "ApplicationState", file = UrlParameter.Optional, state = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
       // RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
}
```

So I am stumped..

Comment: huh... I can't see anything specifically wrong :/

Comment: can you get to any other actions in that controller? Throw an Index action in there to see if your even hitting the controller. Do you have a controller constructor? Put a breakpoint there to see if it's hitting that.

Comment: Please show the controller code.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure your controller class is called DecisionPointController and not DecisionPoint

Answer (score 11):

If your `AreaRegistration` class and `Controller` class are not in the same namespace, you'll be in this situation - the route will match (and [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx/) will confirm this) but you'll get a 404 at the "correct" url.

The solution is to make sure both clases are in the same namespace.

Comment: Also make sure the controller class is correctly named. I spent 2 hours debugging because the filename was correct, but the class name was not

Comment: RouteDebugger link is dead. Please update if you can?

Answer (score 3):

Dumb, but it got me:
Be sure your controller inherits from `Controller`

Comment: inheriting from ControllerBase should work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing

```
app.MapControllers();
```

in my program.cs (.NET 6 and above)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen due to your `Controller` being in another project which references a different version of `System.Web.Mvc`!

I had the same symptoms - the correct route was found, but got a 404! On HttpHandler.ProcessRequest, an exception was thrown saying the handler's controller does not implement `IController`.

Comment: How do you use controller from another dll?

Comment: @jjxtra At the time of answering, I think you just had to put the different namespace in the `MapRoute` helper. With ASP.NET Core now there's a bit extra needed with the `AddApplicationPart` extension

Answer (score 2):

I just recently ran into this same problem.  For me the problem was that I had two controllers with the same name if different namespaces (One was in an area).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no routes guru, but I have always added all parameters for the default argument:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DecisionPointState", // Route name
    "DecisionPoint/ApplicationState/{fileName}/{stateString}", // URL with parameters
    new {controller = "DecisionPoint", 
         action = "ApplicationState"
         fileName = UrlParameter.Optional,
         stateString = UrlParameter.Optional
     } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: I have tried that.. and in this case I am providing both parameters. Thanks

Comment: Nick, I know this sounds a bit crazy, but what happens if you rename the Action to something else? I'm thinking that the name `ApplicationState` is confusing IIS.

Comment: I just tried changing it to 'UpdateState' and it still gives 404

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the answer for the same problem was a matter of needing to "include in project" the relevant controllers and views instead of incorrect routing rules.

When mine were created, they weren't automatically included for some reason. This problem was revealed after I closed and re-opened the solution.

{+1 hate} awarded to Visual Studio for its faulty hyper-automation sending me digging through Web.Config files, trying to tack on extensions, and even trying (and failing) to whip up a decent ErrorController.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that controller class must have **public** access modifier. I wrote down my controller as:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

And since default modifier for classes is **internal**, all actions within this controller didn't match any route.